# Eclipse Code Hinting on JSP with Custom Tags (taglib)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp-tags, code-hinting

I'm developing a JSP tag that have an attribute that works with a set of possible values.
I don't need to enforce this values, but I would like my IDE (*Eclipse*) do some code hinting or auto-completion.

Suppose a tag like this `<mytag:sometag someattribute="value" />`.

The attribute `someattribute` can have any value (remember, I don't need to enforce), but I would like it to suggest you the following list of values: `ValueA`, `ValueB` and `ValueC`

[Nitin Dahyabhai at the Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/210423/) suggested writing a plugin based on `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.modelQueryExtensions` or create templates with the values.

The problem with templates is that I have hundreds of possible values and I have multiple tags.
The problem with writing a plugin is that I haven't time or knowledge to do it.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting such an old question, but I'm curious if you were able to address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In case you end up with writing Eclipse extension for modelQueryExtensions, that should be as simple as:

Create new plug-in: `com.my.taglib`, and add to its `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.modelQueryExtensions">
  <modelQueryExtension
    class="com.my.taglib.MyTaglibModelQueryExtension"
    contentType="org.eclipse.wst.html.core.htmlsource">
  </modelQueryExtension>
</extension>
```

Then implement `com.my.taglib.MyTaglibModelQueryExtension` class:

```
public class MyTaglibModelQueryExtension extends ModelQueryExtension {

    public String[] getAttributeValues(Element e, String namespace, String name) {
        // See XSDModelQueryExtension for an example implementation of this...
    }
}
```